# TypeError: reshape(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray

Tags: pytorch, lime

I am a high school student who doesn't having much experience in using PyTorch and LIME. I'm having a lot of trouble with my image shape. Initially my image shape was (3,224,224), however the LIME algorithm only works with images that are in this shape(...,...,3). As a result, I tried transposing the image earlier. It seemed that I made some more progress by doing that, however, now I am getting a different error. Here is some of my code to understand what I have been doing before the error came up.

```
def get_preprocess_transform():    
transf = transforms.Compose([
  #  transforms.ToPILImage(), #had to convert image to PIL as error was showing up two cells below about needing it in pil
    transforms.Resize(input_size),
    transforms.CenterCrop(input_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    
])    

return transf    

preprocess_transform = get_preprocess_transform() ## use your data_transform but in a method version
```

```
def batch_predict(image):
    model_ft.eval()
    batch = torch.reshape(image,(1,3,224,224))
    print(type(batch))
    
    
    
    logits = model_ft(batch)
    probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
    return probs.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

```
print(img_t.shape)
img_t = torch.reshape(img_t,(1,3,224,224))
test_pred = batch_predict(img_t)
test_pred.squeeze().argmax()
```

```
img_t = np.ones((3, 224, 224))
np.transpose(img_t, (2,1,0)).shape
```

```
img_x = np.transpose(img_t, (2, 1, 0))
print(img_x.shape)
```

```
from lime import lime_image
```

```
explainer = lime_image.LimeImageExplainer()
explanation = explainer.explain_instance(img_x, ## pass your image, do not transform
                                        batch_predict, # classification function
                                        top_labels=5, 
                                        hide_color=0, 
                                        num_samples=1000)
```

[Here is the error message that comes from the "explainer cell"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNLnx.png)

Comment: What's wrong? And how can I fix it? I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

use this command to convert numpy.ndarray to tensor

`img = torch.from_numpy(img).float() #use appropriate name of variable`

Answer (score 2):

You are passing NumPy array instead of `torch.tensor` in the [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html#torch-reshape) method. So better to convert the input to `torch.tensor` in the beginning

therefore, `img_t` should be `torch.tensor` Here are some ways to do it

First, use [`torch.ones`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ones.html#torch-ones) instead numpy `np.ones`

```
img_t = torch.ones((3,224,224))
```

Or use [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html#torch-from-numpy) later to Creates a Tensor from a `numpy.ndarray`

```
img_t = np.ones((3, 224, 224))
img_t = torch.from_numpy(img_t)
```